# is it possible to select a circle area in adobe photoshop 7

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i want to copy a circle area from one picture and paste as a layer into another picture but i only see:

- Rectangle Select or
- Lasso free form select

is there anyway to select a perfect circle area ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep pressing on the rectangular selection tools and you will see the others.  Choose Elliptical.  You can keep SHIFT pressed down to make the selection circular, and the ALT key will change the cursor to the centre point.

In nearly all of the tools in Photoshop (and other Adobe program, as well as CAD and 3D programs), the SHIFT, ALT, CTRL and SPACE keys are important modifiers, so you need to keep your left hand on keyboard.  Experiment with combinations of those keys.

You really ought to get a book or spend some time doing tutorials on the internet, as it will save you a lot of time and frustration in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple. (in Windows) Press 'M' (rectangular select), then 'Shift-M' (elliptical select), then hold Ctrl while you're dragging (this will keep the selection a circle, instead of an ellipse), Ctrl-C to copy, and then Ctrl-V in your other picture to insert.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if the circle is alone in a solid color (ie: white) canvas, is using the magic wand tool, and depending on if it's or not a subtle contrast circle border/background put it lower or higher tolerance in magic wand settings (10 to 32 can work, depending on case), antialiasing setting checked, click on canvas background (outside the circle), ctrl + shift + i (in Windows) to invert the selection, now you can ctrl + c that. The advantage of this is it'd work also for other kind of shapes. Obviously will need help of other commands if there's more complexity in background, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The magic wand tool automatically selects an object or area of your image, using machine learning to discern what you might be trying to select. If you click on the sky, it selects the sky; click on a person's face, and you have the entire face selected in just seconds.